# Testing null hypothesis

Tags: r, economics

I want to test the null hypothesis that all coefficients except the constant term are zero using an F statistic.
I know how to test the hypothesis if some of the variables are zero under null hypothesis as follows:

```
# Unrestricted model
model_u = lm(logwage ~ educ + abil + exper + motheduc + fatheduc + 
broken + sib, data = koop2004)
# Restricted model
model_r = lm(Prc ~ LndSz, data = RealEstate)
# F-Test
require(data.table)
linearHypothesis(model_u, c( "HseSz = 0", "Bdrms = 0"))
```

but I don't know how to estimate a model where all others except intercept are zero under the null hypothesis.

Comment: That test is already done for you and provided if you do `summary(model_u)`.  With that said... if you want to force a coefficient to be 0 then just don't include it in the model.

Comment: If you need help choosing the appropriate statistical test for your hypothesis, you should consider asking your question at [stats.se] instead.